# Setting memory of Java programs that runs from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, memory

I'm running a Java application from Eclipse that need a lot of memory.

Where can i put the <strike>`-Xmms`</strike>`-xms` flag ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set the VM arguments for a specific run configuration:

*Run → Run Configurations... → Arguments Tab → VM arguments*

Btw, you may want to try `-Xms` instead of `-Xmms`.

Comment: Unrecognized option: -Xmms512m
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Comment: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m ( I'm dysleixc )

Answer (score 1):

from the run menu select run configuration.
you can add specific parameters to each of your run configurations individually.