# Memory Error in Stanford CoreNLP (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp

```
package src;

import java.util.Properties;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;

public class NLPTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        StanfordCoreNLP coreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    }

}
```

I ran this sample code in my eclipse but it gives following error:
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Although everything works perfectly when I run Stanford CoreNLP from Command Propmt. Can anybody tell me the solution? Is it related to memory allocation to Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse problem is that you need to set not the amount of memory that Eclipse gets (the `eclipse.ini` file) but rather the amount of memory that a Java program run from Eclipse gets. This is specified in `Run|Run Configurations` as detailed in [other stack overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175188/setting-memory-of-java-programs-that-runs-from-eclipse).

But also, are you running with a 32 bit JVM? You may well need to be running with a 64 bit JVM to be able to allocate enough memory for Stanford CoreNLP to run happily.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse you have `Eclipse.ini` file near to Eclipse.exe

```
-Xmn128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-Xss1m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

Here change the heap size Then your program won't OOM

Comment: maximize your heap size upto -Xmx1024m then run your program

Comment: @blackpearl Change the work space and check,it will resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I thought I should go along with Chris to give an answer (that is some memory values) which is specific to this problem (Core-NLP) rather than just some standard Java with Eclipse guidance.

If you are doing -Xmx1500m, that is likely not enough.  The numbers mentioned in the other numbers, which admittedly are meant just to be examples, are not enough.  If I run with -Xmx3500m, that is good enough to allow the Coreference Resolution part of the pipeline to pass.  As one familiar with Eclipse can tell, that is the area where 64-bit is required (as Chris says) and Eclipse won't let you allocate that much heap memory if you have chosen 32-bit tools.

Answer (score 0):

An OOM or OOME (OutOfMemoryError) simply means that the JVM ran out of memory. When this occurs, you basically have 2 choices:

1.Allow the JVM to use more memory using the -Xmx VM argument. For instance, to allow the JVM to use 1 GB (1024 MB) of memory:

```
java -Xmx1024m HelloWorld
```

2.Improve/Fix the application so that it uses less memory

```
     Start the application with the VM argument -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError. This will tell the VM to produce a heap dump when a OOM occurs:
java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError ...
```

I suggest you to run like this in your command prompt

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx256m HelloWorld
```

here   `-Xms64m` minimum heap size 64mb and `-Xmx256m` maximum heap size 256mb instead `Helloworld` put your `classname`

Comment: Standard output: 
I added the VM argument -Xmx1024m in the run configuration of my program but now I am getting the following error:
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Standard error: 
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Comment: I have a 4gb RAM but when I run the following program:
package src;

public class GetHeapSize {
    public static void main(String[]args){
         
        //Get the jvm heap size.
        long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
         
        //Print the jvm heap size.
        System.out.println("Heap Size = " + heapSize);
    }
}  
I get heap size: 16252928
What's the issue here?

Comment: See you have 4gb RAM but you check your eclipse heap size declared in your .ini file.The problem when the application keeps more and more references to objects and never releases them.

Answer (score 0):

If others stumble across this issue: In my case I could cut memory consumption in half or even more just by upgrading from Java 1.8 to Java 14. Seems like the used Java version has a heavy impact.