# Algorithm comparison in java: test program does not work

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort, hybrid

I'm trying to compare the execution of the java implementation of QuickSort and its hybrid version (using InsertionSort for those partitions which are smaller than an integer k). I wrote a test class to analyze the behaviour of the algorithms for some values ok k (1 <= k <= 25). For each value of k the class compares for different sizes of the input array the two algorithms.

I can't run the program for some values of the size of the array, for instance for values greater than 4000. The execution reach some different values and then freeze, after a while it will finish but I have no output of the computation. (I'm using eclipse).

 What could be the problem? I wish to perform the comparation of the two algoritms for an array size from 10 to 10000 (at least).
 The code is listed below:

```
public class Main {

private static final int MAX_K = 25;
private static final int MAX_SIZE = 4500;
private static final int ADD_SIZE = 100;
private static int size = 10;

private static QuickSort qSort;
private static HybridSort hSort;

private static void initArray(int[] A) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        // A[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100000);
        A[i] = rand.nextInt();

    }
}

private static int[] A = new int[10];
private static int[] B = new int[10];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write("Init file");

        qSort = new QuickSort();
        hSort = new HybridSort();

        /************************************************/
        /* Comparison */
        /************************************************/

        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_K; i++) {
            hSort.setK(i);

            int p = 0;
            for (int j = size; j <= MAX_SIZE; j = j + ADD_SIZE) {

                A = new int[j];
                B = new int[j];
                initArray(A);
                initArray(B);

                long sTime = System.nanoTime();
                qSort.quickSort(A, 0, A.length - 1);
                long qDuration = System.nanoTime() - sTime;

                sTime = System.nanoTime();
                hSort.hybridSort(B, 0, B.length - 1);
                long hDuration = System.nanoTime() - sTime;

                out.append(/* "\nA: " +printArray(A)+ */"K: " + i + " A["
                        + j + "]\tQ = " + qDuration + " H = " + hDuration
                        + "\n");

                String h = Long.toString(hDuration);
                String q = Long.toString(qDuration);

                if (h.length() < q.length()) {
                    p++;
                    out.append("\t#OUTPERM for K: "
                            + i
                            + "\t\t"
                            + hDuration
                            + "\t\t < \t\t "
                            + qDuration
                            + "\t\t\t\t| A[]\t\t"
                            + A.length
                            + ((q.length() - h.length()) == 2 ? "\t Magn. 2"
                                    : "") + "\n");
                }
            }
            if (p > 0)
                out.append("#P= " + p + " for K= " + i + "\n\n");
        }
        out.append("Close file");
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}

}
```

The algorithm classes:

```
public class QuickSort {


public void quickSort(int[] A, int left, int right){
    if (left < right) {
        int m = Partition(A, left, right);
        quickSort(A, left, m-1);
        quickSort(A, m, right);
    }
}


private int Partition(int[] A, int left, int right){
    int pivot = A[right];
    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    while (true) {
        while ( (A[j] > pivot)) {
            j--;
        }
        while ((A[i] < pivot)) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i < j){
            int swap = A[j];
            A[j] = A[i];
            A[i] = swap;
        }else{
            return i;
        }
    }
}

}
```

```
public class HybridSort {

int k;
int m;
InsertionSort iSort;

public HybridSort() {
    k = 3;
    iSort = new InsertionSort();
}

public void hybridSort(int[] A, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        if ((right - left) < k) {
                                    iSort.sort(A,left,right);
        } else {                
            m = Partition(A, left, right);
            hybridSort(A, left, m - 1);
            hybridSort(A, m, right);
        }
    }
}

private int Partition(int[] A, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = A[right];
    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    while (true) {
        while ((A[j] > pivot) && (j >= 0)) {
            j--;
        }
        while ((A[i] < pivot) && (i < A.length)) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            int swap = A[j];
            A[j] = A[i];
            A[i] = swap;
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }
}


public void setK(int k) {
    this.k = k;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at Arrays.sort() which does much the same thing?

Comment: It is an exercise, I have to write all the classes (at least for the sorting algos).

Comment: But I assume you can still read the sources for educational purposes. ;)

Comment: I don't see you using your iSort member in your hybrid.  Is that causing a problem?

Comment: iSort is used, I forgot it when I pasted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of `Partition` is not correct. Consider the small test below (I made `Partition` `static` for my convenience).

Both `while` loops won't be executed, because `A[i] == A[j] == pivot`. Moreover, `i<j`, so the two elements will be swapped, resulting in exactly the same array. Therefore, the outer `while` loop becomes infinite.

The same problem occurs for any array for which the first and last element are the same.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {1, 1};
        Partition(A, 0, 1);
    }

    private static int Partition(int[] A, int left, int right){
        int pivot = A[right];
        int i = left;
        int j = right;

        while (true) {
            while ( (A[j] > pivot)) {
                j--;
            }
            while ((A[i] < pivot)) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i < j){
                int swap = A[j];
                A[j] = A[i];
                A[i] = swap;
            }else{
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shame on me! I look at the code more than once cause I thought of an infinite loop; since I wasn't able to find the mistake I considered it as correct. Thank you for your complete answer and hint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing memory settings for your code to run in eclipse.
You may find this [Setting memory of Java programs that runs from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175188/setting-memory-of-java-programs-that-runs-from-eclipse) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips / possible solution?:

I haven't read your implementation of QuickSort or HybridSort but I am assuming they are correct.

1. If you are comparing the performance of two algorithms you should most definitely compare their performance to indentical inputs. Currently you are generating two random arrys (albeit of the same size). This isn't necessarily going to be an accurate test as I can easily find a test case where one algorithm will outperform the other if the random generator is out to troll you.
2. Your logic for comparing the two algorithms is a bit weird and incorrect according to me. Why do you compare the lengths of the strings of the times? according to your logic 1 is the same as 9 and 1,000,000,000 is the same as 9,999,999,999 which is clearly incorrect. One algorithm is almost 10 times faster than the other.
3. Moreover, one reason for no output might be the reason that you are only outputing when hybridsort is better than quicksort and not the other way around. I am sure there are other reasons as well but this could be one easily noticable reason (if your implementations are incorrect).

   I do notice that you close your outputstream which is good as that is a very common reason why there is no output. You should however, close steams in the `finally` section of the try-catch as then they are guaranteed to close. You could be getting an IOException and in your case this would also not close the outputsteam and consequently lead to no ouput in your file.

Here is a sample structure that I would follow for doing any comparitive testing. It is easy to read and easy to debug with enough output for you to figure out which algorithm performs better. This is merely a suggestion.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;

public class Tester {

  private static int[] initArray(int size) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = rand.nextInt();
    }
    return arr;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX_ITERATIONS = 25;
    final int INITIAL_ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 4500;
    final int ARRAY_SIZE_INCREMENT = 100;

    long start;
    int[] score = null;

    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
      out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("out.txt"));
      for (int arraySize = INITIAL_ARRAY_SIZE; arraySize <= MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; arraySize += ARRAY_SIZE_INCREMENT) {
        // score[0] is for quickSort and score[1] is for hybridSort
        score = new int[2];
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < MAX_ITERATIONS; iteration++) {
          int[] testArray = initArray(arraySize);
          int[] testArrayCopy = new int[arraySize];
          System.arraycopy(testArray, 0, testArrayCopy, 0, arraySize);

          start = System.nanoTime();
          // Do quicksort here using testArray
          long qSortfinish = System.nanoTime() - start;

          System.arraycopy(testArray, 0, testArrayCopy, 0, arraySize);
          start = System.nanoTime();
          // Do hybridsort here using testArrayCopy
          long hybridSortfinish = System.nanoTime() - start;

          // Keep score
          if (qSortfinish < hybridSortfinish)
            score[0]++;
          else if (qSortfinish > hybridSortfinish) {
            score[1]++;
          } else {
            score[0]++;
            score[1]++;
          }
        }
        out.println("Array Size: " + arraySize + " QuickSort: " + score[0] + " HybridSort: " + score[1]);
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (out != null)
        out.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I considered the length of the strings of the sorting duration times in order to have a difference of at least one order of magnitude. As you wrote I considered an hypothetical running time of 2345 equivalent as another of 4690, which is twice faster. Is it completly wrong? In asymptotic analisys we have to consider the order of magnitude with O-notation, so I have applied the same principle.

Comment: Yes, but if one is consistently better than the other, you better use the one that is better. You are doing tests, you don't need to "ignore the constants" here but if that IS a requirement then go ahead.