# How I can load a model in TDB TripleStore

Tags: java, web-services, rdf, jena, tdb

I have a question for you:

I would like to load a file on my Jena TDB TripleStore.
My file is very big, about 80Mb and about 700000 triples RDF. When I try to load it, the execution stops working or takes a very long time.

I'm using this code that I do run on a Web Service:

```
        String file = "C:\\file.nt";
        String directory;
        directory = "C:\\tdb";
        Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory);

        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        TDBLoader.loadModel(model, file );
        dataset.addNamedModel("http://nameFile", model); 

        return model;
```

Sometimes I get an error of Java heap space:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.jena.riot.tokens.TokenizerText.parseToken(TokenizerText.java:170)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.tokens.TokenizerText.hasNext(TokenizerText.java:86)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.PeekIterator.fill(PeekIterator.java:50)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.PeekIterator.next(PeekIterator.java:92)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.nextToken(LangEngine.java:99)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangNTriples.parseOne(LangNTriples.java:67)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangNTriples.runParser(LangNTriples.java:54)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTFactoryImpl$1.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:142)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:859)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:255)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:241)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT_Web.read(RDFReaderRIOT_Web.java:96)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:241)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBLoader.loadAnything(TDBLoader.java:294)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBLoader.loadModel(TDBLoader.java:125)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBLoader.loadModel(TDBLoader.java:119)
```

How I can load this file in a model Jena and save it in TDB? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [allocate more memory for your JVM at statup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2294280/2528639). When you have too little, the process will spend too much time performing garbage collection, and will ultimately fail.

For example, start your JVM with 4 GB of memory by:

```
java -Xms4G -XmxG
```

If you are in an IDE such as Eclipse, you can [change your run configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4175188/2528639) so that the application has additional memory as well.

Aside from that, the only change that jumps out at me is that you are using an in-memory model for the actual loading operation, when you can actually use a model backed by TDB instead. This can help to alleviate your memory problems because TDB dynamially moves its indexes to disk.

Change:

```
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory);
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
TDBLoader.loadModel(model, file );
dataset.addNamedModel("http://nameFile", model);
```

to this:

```
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory);
Model model = dataset.getNamedModel("http://nameFile");
TDBLoader.loadModel(model, file );
```

Now your system depends on TDB's ability to make good decisions about when to leave data in memory and when to flush it to disk.

Comment: I think the answer is simply the second part -- skip the in memory model and you won't need to bump the heap allocation.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I have done this modify and now it works!

Comment: Rob, this solution is good, but I have noticed a error that I have reported in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865560/error-when-i-load-rdf-triples-in-tdb-triple-store?noredirect=1#comment40476748_25865560