# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError although not using all the memory

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm running some Java code doing some crypto stuff and it gets a  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

I modified the `eclipse.ini` from `-Xmx1024m` to `-Xmx2048m`.

I opened the task manager and I run the app again and I saw that the JVM is consuming all the 2048 MB of RAM and still the same error. Then I put 3500 MB, but in the task manager the JVM still used only 2048 MB of RAM and still the same error.

What can I do? What other info should I publish to help you help me?

Comment: Try getting the heap dump and check what exactly is consuming the space.  Check JMap on how to get heap memory dump. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eclipse.ini increases the memory given to Eclipse not to your program

You need to change the run configuration of your program.

- In the run menu , select run configuration
- Select your run configuration
- Select arguments tab
- In VM arguments you can add -Xmx2048m

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you're setting the amount of memory that Eclipse uses, but what you really want to do is set the amount of memory that *your* code uses - these are 2 different things.

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175188/setting-memory-of-java-programs-that-runs-from-eclipse) for how to set the memory of your running code