# Limit RAM usage Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, ram

I'm writing a java program using the Eclipse IDE (Kepler Service Release 1) that is causing the JVM to hog more memory than it needs.  I don't run out of RAM but the fan really ramps up.  I'd like to experiment with limiting the JVM's seemingly godlike power over system memory.

Apparently there is a way to start the JVM with a switch that will limit the amount of RAM it will allow the program to consume.  I know there is a setting for this in the Eclipse.ini file but that is for the IDE itself.  What I want to do is limit the RAM usage for the java program when I start it in dev/debug mode.  Does anyone know how that might be accomplished?

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175188/setting-memory-of-java-programs-that-runs-from-eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the VM arguments for a specific run configuration they can be found at

Run → Run Configurations → Arguments Tab → VM arguments

you can do something like -Xms512