# Is it possible to limit the memory in Tomcat for a single WAR app?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a vaadin app where if I don't limit the RAM, the WAR will run it up to 2.5+gb in Tomcat but if I limit it to 1gb in eclipse using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175188/setting-memory-of-java-programs-that-runs-from-eclipse) the program will stay steady around 700mb(when no action)-1.2gb (when running a large dataset).

Is there a way to export this war with the memory constraint? I have other war apps on the same Tomcat server, but this one is the only one that runs rampant. Or is it better practice to create a separate virtual server and set the memory constraint in Tomcat just for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse runs each program in a separate JVM.

A Tomcat instance runs inside of a JVM, and so will all web apps deployed in it. You could start a second Tomcat instance (and thus a second JVM) and set the specific memory constraints for each JVM